# Automate deployment of wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I'm currently deploying a wpf client application "manually". The application has to be deployed to one machine only.

This is what I'm doing:

1. Build the application ("Release")
2. Connect to the network via VPN ("SmartTek VPN Client")
3. Connect to the machine via RDP.
4. Copy the bin of the application to a folder on the machine.

I wonder how/what of this process can be automated. I could use the "ClickOnce Deployment" (instead of step 3-4) but as far as I understood an ftp server is needed for this. I'm not sure if this can be done (due to security restrictions). Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Most of projects have their own build system, like [Team City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamCity), so first of all i recommend you to find something similar which suits your possibilities and requirements ( as far as i remember, TeamCity can work with wpf as well).

Also there can be simple solution, if you are the only developer (or man who is allowed to deploy new version to server): you need to create some 'shared' file server (network connection, ftp, SVN-based) and simple button 'Download'.
So when you click this button, some handler on your server should load new build form the source and publish.

Anyway, i recommend you to use some continuous integration system

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deploying a WPF project. Could you use ClickOnce framework? I know it's quite "old" but it will work as a charm for you.

Build -> Deploy to somewhere reachable VIA web -> Customer will browse the url and ClickOnce itself will deploy the new output.